# Swift Client for activeMQ

Tags: swift, swift2, activemq-classic, swift3, activemq-cpp

Do we have any framework in Swift that is highly compatible with ActiveMQ?(Enables user to create/Remove, along with Subscribe/Publish(Usual) on topic & queue) I've tried Moscapsule and it works on topic but not on queue(apparently). Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

If Swift can work with C/C++ bindings check into these options:

C++ client: http://activemq.apache.org/cms/
C client (not actively maintained): https://github.com/fusesource/fusemq-c

Otherwise, look into the STOMP protocol.. it is a text-based protocol that is simple to implement for languages without native bindings for ActiveMQ's native OpenWire protocol if none of the available bindings work for you.

STOMP clients: https://stomp.github.io/implementations.html#STOMP_Clients
ActiveMQ STOMP support: http://activemq.apache.org/stomp.html